Наследование сущностей EF
Есть 2 разных контекста БД, и в каждом будет практически одинаковый набор сущностей, но некоторые из них слегка отличаются. Думал выделить общее в библиотеку и от нее уже унаследовать изменения, но возникли сомнения.
Допустим есть сущность PersonEntity. Как видно из примера ниже она ссылается на 6 других сущностей(A,B,..F), что является реальным примером(кроме именования). Между всеми этими сущностями установлена связь один ко многим.
public class PersonEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public AEntity A { get; set; }

    public BEntity B { get; set; }

    public CEntity C { get; set; }

    public DEntity D { get; set; }

    public EEntity E { get; set; }

    public FEntity F { get; set; }
}

public class AEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonEntity> Persons { get; set; }
}

Что если для первого контекста я хочу оставить класс "AEntity" таким же, а для второго добавить в него новое свойство к примеру email. Ок, тогда я сделаю базовый класс и унаследуюсь от него два раза для каждого контекста.
public abstract class ABaseEntity<TPerson>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TPerson> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class AEntity : ABaseEntity<PersonEntity>
{

}

public class A2Entity : ABaseEntity<PersonEntity>
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

А что если мне нужно проделать тоже самое, но для PersonEntity? Пусть для первого контекста будет AEntity, а для второго A2Entity и так для каждой из 6 зависимостей. Делать generic на 6 типов? Да, я могу, но думаю это плохая практика.
В данный момент сделал примерно такую реализацию, но может можно сделать еще лучше?
public abstract class PersonBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEntity : PersonBaseEntity
{
    public AEntity A { get; set; }

    //Аналогично для остальных свойств
}

public class Person2Entity : PersonBaseEntity
{
    public A2Entity A { get; set; }

    //Аналогично для остальных свойств
}

P.S И как уследить, что в PersonEntity и в Person2Entity одинаковый набор свойств(A,B,C,D...)?

Это и есть причина, почему абстракции - не работают. На самом деле - работают. Но перестают работать ровно тогда - когда перестают быть абстракциями. Что такое абстракция? Это самоописание типа, в пределах самого себя же, не выходя за рамки этого типа. А вы к типу приматываете например и-мейл, и приматываете именно к типу, как часть типа. Вот это и есть - не верно. Потому что абстракция и-мейла - это собственная абстракция, в своём дереве абстракций. А ваши типы - это собственные деревья. И пересекаться они не должны.

Пересекаются два разных дерева абстракций - через интерфейсы. Т.е. у ваших типов должен быть интерфейс. Интерфейс и-мейл-able. Это значит, что ваш тип имеет допустимую возможность [-able] иметь и-мейл. И какую то реализацию этой допустимой возможности иметь и-мейл.

Абстракции - это абстракции) Относитесь к ним именно так. Абстракции никакого отношения к программированию - не имеют. Они существуют вне программирования. Что это значит? А это значит то, что соберите дерево абстракций на бумашке. Без каких либо реализаций вовсе, они не нужны. Задайте себе вопрос - что такое это самое "Person"? Надо полагать, что "Person" - это вообще то человек) И у человека есть точно определённый набор параметров. Но это никак не и-мейл) Опишите человека. Это и есть - "Person". Т.е. родительская абстракция "Person" - это вообще то внезапно[!] - "Human".

А конкретно в вашем случае - ничего никогда работать и не будет. Потому что изначально собрано всё логически криво, и оно не способно отражать реальность. Любая неспособность отражать логическую абстрактную реальность - приведёт к дальнейшей неспособности расширения описания этой реальности. Т.е. такие абстракции - лживые. Именно на уровне логики. Именно лживые. С ними ничего сделать нельзя. Бесполезно. Нельзя сделать потому, что любая манипуляция такими лживыми абстракциями - будет порождать лживые абстрактные утверждения над абстракциями. Это когда землекоп - родитель кирпича и так далее.

Вы пишете: "Да, я могу, но думаю это плохая практика." В данном случае вы думаете принципиально не верно. Потому что это вопрос логики, а не практики. Если логика есть - то она есть, а если логики нет - ну значит её и нет. И никакая практика на логику не влияет, и никогда влиять не будет. На логику и на способы построения логических систем - практика не влияет. Логика существует независимо от практики. Т.е. сколько бы вы не практиковались или же практиковались - от этого первичная логика абстракций - не изменится. В этом суть.

@InterceptorTSK спасибо за ответы, но вы говорите на слишком непонятном для меня уровне абстракций. Хотелось бы более приземленного совета/примера. Или этот совет является выделением несколько десятков разных интерфейсов(IEmailable и.т.п)?

ответ дан на более менее предельно понятном [общепринятом простейшем] языке, использующем минимальное количество сущностей из словаря языка; эти общепринятые сущности из языка не имеют множественных трактовок, т.е. ответ не может как либо истрактовываться, т.е. иметь множественные смыслы, неопределённости и так далее

Пример работы абстракций.
Есть абстракция котика, есть абстракция пёсика. И есть абстракция животного.
Постройте граф [дерево] абстракций. В данном случае граф - тривиален, это:
        Животное
        /      \
    Котик      Пёсик

Верифицируйте граф абстракций. Т.е. получите все возможные утверждения из этого графа, и вот же они:

Котик - это котик
Пёсик - это пёсик
Животное - это животное
Котик - это животное
Пёсик - это животное

Если вы построите граф иначе - вы получите набор ложных утверждений.
Только из исправно построенного графа абстракций - можно получить набор истинных утверждений. И это очевидные утверждения, но есть вовсе не очевидные, вот они:

Котик абстрагированный до животного - это животное
Пёсик абстрагированный до животного - это животное

Но тут получается аццкий фокус. Прямиком из ада. Потому что иначе не скажешь. Потому что подавляющее большинство - к этому никогда не готовы.
Если котик - это котик, а пёсик - это пёсик, то они не равны. Но будучи абстрагированы к животному - равны. Разницы - нет. И как так? А вот так. Так работают абстракции. Они для того и есть. Были две абстракции, абстракция котика, абстракция пёсика. А стала одна - абстракция животного. Именно - одна . Потому что абстрагированного котика до животного и абстрагированного пёсика до животного - различить невозможно . Две абстракции животного - бессмысленны. Это же полные копии. Потому [доказательно] и существует ровно одна абстракция животного.
Суть аццкого [именно аццкого] фокуса тут в том, что пара чего либо - может быть равна, а может быть не равна, в пределах пары. Смотря до чего вы абстрагируете эту пару - такой ответ [утверждение] и получите. И такое работает только в абстракциях. Абстракции - заранее никогда не определены. И любые утверждения над абстракциями, заранее - никогда не определены.
Что такое "абстрагирование"? Это потеря информации до такой [нужной] степени, что бы любое иное [подходящее] тоже будучи способно потерять информацию - в итоге было сводимо к чему то одному [одинаковому/не различимому/не имеющему разницы], что называют родительской абстракцией.
И есть обратная операция - это "конкретизация". Это когда абстрактное приобретает информацию и становится менее абстрактным, т.е. более конкретным, это называется потомком, относительно родительской абстракции.
Суть тут в том, что например абстракцию "цвета", "кирпича", "квазиромбокубооктаэдра" и "большого адронного коллайдера" - вы в вышепостроенное дерево абстракций котика/пёсика/животного - никак не прилепите.
Потому что выше написано про "абстрагирование" - это такая степень потери информации, что бы у какого то А, и у какого то Б - получилась общая [одинаковая/не различимая] суть.
Как можно [до какой степени терять информацию о кирпиче], что бы абстрагировать кирпич до животного? Понятное дело - никак. Именно потому [и только потому, доказательно] - кирпич невозможно прилепить в дерево абстракций котика/пёсика/животного
Тогда что делать? Строить графы абстракций) Если построенное дерево логически не противоречит само себе [в рамках самоописания самого себя] - значит это годное [не противоречивое] дерево.
Но деревьев много. И они абстрактно - не пересекаются. Никак. Есть дерево где есть абстракция "цвета", а есть дерево где есть абстракция "цены", и так далее. Но эти абстракции существуют в рамках собственных деревьев абстракций.
Для того что бы описать дерево абстракций - нужно построить дерево, проверить дерево. И в этом дереве, понятное дело - хватит типичного наследования и полей.
Но для каких либо связей [отношений] между деревьями - нужны интерфейсы.
